# Xcode folders and groups confusion

Tags: c++, xcode, include

I'm using Xcode (with C++) and my project layout (in the file system, not in Xcode) looks like this:

> SubfolderA
>
> -file_A_1, file_A_2
>
> SubfolderB
>
> -file_B_1, file_B_2

Right now I've set up this structure in Xcode via groups. And so, when I want to include file_A_2 in file_B_1, I write `#include "file_A_2"` in file_B_1.

Is there some way to make an inclusion look like `#include "/SubfolderA/file_A_2"`, so that I can easily see to what directory/subfolder an included file belongs?

Comment: Sure. Just use #include "../SubfolderA/file"  instead of starting with "/ which refers to the root of your file system.

Comment: @johnelemans yes, but if the project are being developed across multiple machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly, in Xcode's `Build Settings` I've added to `User Header Search Paths` non-recursive path to my project. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

One way to see what's going on is to look at the *Build Log* and expand the line for compiling `sourcefile.m`.  Look at the `-I` options being passed to the compiler.

If it's not to your liking you can add the source tree in the *Build Settings* > *Header Search Paths* to include `$(ProjectDir)/srcroot` and make it *recursive*, which saves you from adding each sub-folder individually.

In my experience this has never been necessary, however, as far as I can remember.

As far as the Xcode folders are concerned, if the top-level source folder is added then all sub-folders are automatically added when you add them to the filesystem, saving the hassle of keeping them in sync.  You might need to add the top-level folder under the *Source Files* group for this to work, however.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up here when I was having an issue with XCode while trying to include a header in a group by doing

`#include "MyGroup/MyHeader.h"`

Turns out the project structure and the file system weren't in sync, so I just had to remove my group from the project, put it in the correct place in Finder, then drag and drop it back into the project in the correct place and it worked for me.

I'm not sure if this is necessary or not, but I also have already set up my app's working directory because I am doing some game programming and need to be able to load in .png and make textures.